# How to use parameters in on-click js function in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, parameter-passing

I am using a template HTML to display all my objects and I was wanting to use unique IDs to call a JS function. The ID refers to a div element that expands when some text is clicked, as follows:

```
function more(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    console.log('open')
}
```

How do I go about passing a different ID parameter for each object within some HTML tags? Like so:

```
onclick="return more(<id>)";
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post the relevant HTML markup and also the HTML element to which `onclick="return more(<id>)";` and what element id you want to refer here `<id>`?

Comment: You want to pass the elements own `id`, as in `<div id="123"></div>`? In that case you can write `onclick="return more(this.id)";`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the id as a string

```js
function more(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.color = "green";
  console.log('open')
}
```

```html
<button id='someId' onclick="more('someId')"> Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ready to go bounty hunting?

```js
function more(id){
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#treasures {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img id="treasures" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550565360-6986a92b7169?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" alt="img">
<button onClick="more('treasures')">Press to unlock</button>
```